# script to show nested groups does not show all the members

Tags: powershell

I have created a PowerShell script that shows all the members of an AD group, including the nested ones:

```
 Function Get-NestedGroupsAndMembers
 {

  Param
   (
    [String] $DomainName,
    [String] $ADGroupName,
    [Int]    $Level = 0,
    [Switch] $IncludeNestedGroups
   )

  $arrTable         = @()
  $LevelCounter     = $Level
  $valMember        = 1
  Try
   {
    $ServerHostname   = $(Get-ADDomainController -DomainName $DomainName -Discover).HostName[0]
    $Members          = (Get-ADGroup -Identity $ADGroupName -Server $ServerHostname -Properties Members).Members
    $MemberCount      = $Members.Count
   }
    Catch
   {
    $Record = [ordered] @{"Domain"="";"Group"="";"Consolidated Groupname"="";"SAMAccountName"="";"Mail"="";"DisplayName"="";"objectClass"="";"Level"="";"Error"=""}
    $Record."Domain"                  = $DomainName
    $Record."Group"                   = $ADGroupName
    $Record."Consolidated Groupname"  = "$DomainName\$ADGroupName"
    $Record."SAMAccountName"          = ""
    $Record."Mail"                    = ""
    $Record."DisplayName"             = "" 
    $Record."objectClass"             = ""
    $Record."Level"                   = ""
    $Record."Error"                   = "Error on '$DomainName\$ADGroupName' with server '$ServerHostname': $($_.Exception.Message)" 
    $arrTable                        += New-Object PSObject -Property $Record
    Return $arrTable
   }
  
  Write-Progress -Id $($Level+1) -Activity "Processing the groups" -Status "Processing the group $DomainName\$ADGroupname"

  ForEach ($Member in $Members)
   {
    Try
     {
      Write-Progress -Activity "Processing all the members in the group $DomainName\$ADGroupName" -Status "Processing member $valMember of $MemberCount members." -Id $($Level+2) -ParentId $($Level+1) -PercentComplete ($valMember / $MemberCount * 100)
      $MemberDetails = Get-ADObject -Server $ServerHostname -Filter {DistinguishedName -eq $Member} -Properties SAMAccountName, Mail, displayName,objectclass
      if ($MemberDetails.ObjectClass -eq "User")
       {
        $Record = [ordered] @{"Domain"="";"Group"="";"Consolidated Groupname"="";"SAMAccountName"="";"Mail"="";"DisplayName"="";"objectClass"="";"Level"="";"Error"=""}
        $Record."Domain"                  = $DomainName
        $Record."Group"                   = $ADGroupName
        $Record."Consolidated Groupname"  = "$DomainName\$ADGroupName"
        $Record."SAMAccountName"          = $MemberDetails.SAMAccountName
        $Record."Mail"                    = $MemberDetails.Mail
        $Record."DisplayName"             = $MemberDetails.DisplayName
        $Record."objectClass"             = $MemberDetails.objectClass
        $Record."Level"                   = $Level
        $Record."Error"                   = "" 
        $arrTable                        += New-Object PSObject -Property $Record
        $valMember ++
       }
        else
       {
        If ($IncludeNestedGroups)
         {
          $LevelCounter++
          $arrTable += Get-NestedGroupsAndMembers -DomainName $DomainName -ADGroupName $($MemberDetails.SAMAccountName) -Level $LevelCounter
         } # End If ($IncludeNestedGroups)
       }
     }
     Catch
     {
      $Record = [ordered] @{"Domain"="";"Group"="";"Consolidated Groupname"="";"SAMAccountName"="";"Mail"="";"DisplayName"="";"objectClass"="";"Level"="";"Error"=""}
      $Record."Domain"                  = $DomainName
      $Record."Group"                   = $ADGroupName
      $Record."Consolidated Groupname"  = "$DomainName\$ADGroupName"
      $Record."SAMAccountName"          = ""
      $Record."Mail"                    = ""
      $Record."DisplayName"             = "" 
      $Record."objectClass"             = ""
      $Record."Level"                   = ""
      $Record."Error"                   = "Error on '$DomainName\$ADGroupName' with server '$ServerHostname': $($_.Exception.Message)" 
      $arrTable                        += New-Object PSObject -Property $Record
      Write-Host "Error on '$DomainName\$ADGroupName' with server '$ServerHostname': $($_.Exception.Message)"
     }
   } # End ForEach ($Member in $Members)
   Write-Progress -Id $($Level+2) -ParentId ($Level+1) -Completed -Activity "Nothing"

  Return $arrTable
 
 } # End Function Get-NestedGroupsAndMembers

 Clear-Host 
 $CurrentPath    = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
 $GroupName      = "Demo - DummyGroup1"
 $FileName       = (Join-Path $CurrentPath $GroupName) + ".csv"
 $Results        = Get-NestedGroupsAndMembers -DomainName $((Get-ADDomain).DNSRoot) -ADGroupName $GroupName -IncludeNestedGroups | Sort-Object -Property Level
 If ($Results) 
  {
   $DelimiterChar  = ";"
   $Results | Export-CSV $FileName -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter $DelimiterChar -Encoding UTF8
   Write-Host "$FileName has been created."
  }
```

The script works... only for one level.

The first group is **Demo - Dummygroup 1** with a couple of members. That group contains **Demo - Dummygroup 2** with members. And the second group contains the group **Demo - Dummygroup3** with members. And what happens: only the first 2 groups are inventoried and not the third group.

So, there is something wrong with my script, but I do not know what.

Comment: You might find [`PSADTree`](https://github.com/santisq/PSADTree) useful. It does exactly what you're looking for and does not require de AD Module

Answer (score 0):

The most stupid error ever...

I changed

```
       If ($IncludeNestedGroups)
         {
          $LevelCounter++
          $arrTable += Get-NestedGroupsAndMembers -DomainName $DomainName -ADGroupName $($MemberDetails.SAMAccountName) -Level $LevelCounter
         } # End If ($IncludeNestedGroups)
```

to:

```
       If ($IncludeNestedGroups)
         {
          $LevelCounter++
          $arrTable += Get-NestedGroupsAndMembers -DomainName $DomainName -ADGroupName $($MemberDetails.SAMAccountName) -Level $LevelCounter -IncludeNestedGroups
         } # End If ($IncludeNestedGroups)
```

Problem solved....